# Get more than 10 results when searching from Google Chrome address bar

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

I usually set the search results for Google to 100; 10 is way too small for my usage.

However, when searching through the address bar of Google Chrome, it always shows 10 results, regardless of my settings. If I go to http://google.com/ first and search the same thing, it displays 100 results.

Why is this happening, and how can I get my 100 results even when searching from the Google Chrome address bar?

Comment: It works for me. But it only works if instant results are set to "Never show Instant results."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change this

<s>`{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQ‌​ueryForSuggestion}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:instantFieldTrialGrou‌​pParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s`</s>

Somehow I cannot get my browser to use {parameter} style queries so here is what worked for me

```
https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=%s
```

to include `num=100` in the settings of the browser `chrome://settings/searchEngines`.

The settings for Google search app does <s>not</s> control the query *to an extent* within the browser itself (If you are incognito, the above query will not work).

Comment: This has the side-benefit that it works in Incognito mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this bookmarklets: num=100

Google Search URL Parameters – Query String Anatomy

http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy

Hope this help. Ley us know.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to appending `num=100` to the URL in the Search Engines entry, you can also simply log into a Google account and set your preferences. When you subsequently do a search (from anywhere so long as it is not in Incognito mode), it should do so with the parameters you specified.